# Failed to install apk file in android?

Tags: android-emulator

I am installing apk file in android emulator. But when I gave the command ADB INSTALL CALENDAR.APK in command prompt it is displaying the error as **Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]**. What would be the reason? Can anybody help me regarding this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

[All Android packages must be signed to be installed](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html), well at least since version 1.6.
So that particular package is presumably older. You can get a newer one (or recompile yourself if you have the sources), or use an older version in your emulator (1.5).